# Acessing array of array of hash pointers

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, reference, yaml

This is my YAML File

```
  standalone_execution:  
  - utpsm_executable: &seid_01   
     name: tpsm_BE         
     rulesfile: [*rulesid_02,*rulesid_01]
     target_list: [*runid_01]

  - utpsm_executable: &seid_02
     name: tpsm_LE         
     rulesfile: [*rulesid_01,*rulesid_02]
     target_list: [*runid_02,*runid_01]

  rules_file: 
  - rules_file_id: &rulesid_01 
     name: tpsm_rulesfile_LE 
     hostname:       

  - rules_file_id: &rulesid_02
     name: tpsm_rulesfile_BE        
     hostname:  

  run_target_platforms: 
  - run_target_id: &runid_01
     target_connection_info: 
      run_target_hostname: 
      run_target_username: 
      run_target_password: 

  - run_target_id: &runid_02
     target_connection_info: 
      run_target_hostname: 
      run_target_username: 
      run_target_password:
```

This is how I parse the Yaml :

```
   $yaml_input = YAML::XS::LoadFile("$input_file");
   Yaml_Lib::parse_yaml($yaml_input);
```

here is my function from where I extract the parameters

```
sub parse_yaml_standalone($) {
    my ($yaml_input) = @_;

    $standalone_exec = $yaml_input->{standalone_execution};

    @utpsm_exec    = ();
    @se_exec_name  = ();
    @se_tgt_list   = ();
    @se_rulesfile  = ();
    @se_rules_name = ();

    @se_run_target_controls = ();
    @se_run_target_controls = ();

    my $k = 0;
    my $j = 0;
    my $i = 0;

    for my $seindex ( @$standalone_exec ) {

        $utpsm_exec[$k]   = $seindex->{utpsm_executable};
        $se_exec_name[$k] = $utpsm_exec[$k]->{name};
        $se_tgt_list[$k]  = $utpsm_exec[$k]->{target_list};
        $se_rulesfile[$k] = $utpsm_exec[$k]->{rulesfile};

        for my $rindex ( @{ $se_rulesfile[$k] } ) {
            $se_rules_name[$j] = $rindex->{name};
            $j++;
        }

        for my $run_index ( @{ $se_tgt_list[$k] } ) {
            $se_run_target_controls[$i] = $run_index->{target_controls};
            $se_run_target_types[$i]    = $se_run_target_controls[$i]->{run_target_type};
            $se_run_target_active[$i]   = $se_run_target_controls[$i]->{run_target_active};
            $i++;
        }

        $k++;

    }    #end of main for

    print "yaml rules: @se_rules_name\n";
}
```

Here, each of the target_list element should run with every rulesfile element, so i write the following code but for index = 1, I don't get the desire results, can anybody correct me where i am going wrong ?

```
my $i = 0;
my $j = 0;

foreach my $se_index ( @{$Yaml_Lib::standalone_exec} ) {
    print "parent hash : $se_index\n";

    foreach my $se_runid ( @{ $Yaml_Lib::se_tgt_list[$i] } ) {

        my $pid = fork();
        die "INFO :: Cannot fork new process for run target on host : $!" unless defined($pid);

        # In Child Processing
        if ( $pid == 0 ) {

            my $k    = 0;
            my $cpid = ($$);
            print "INFO :: In run target : child $j process , pid : ($$)\n";
            Client_Lib::client_logs($cpid);

            #send the tpsm exec($i in this case) details as well with run targets(by $j)
            print "child hash $se_index\n";

            foreach my $rindex ( @{ $Yaml_Lib::se_rulesfile[$i] } ) {
                print "rules array : $rindex\n";
                Client_Lib::cap_prints( $Client_Lib::prints_file, "$Yaml_Lib::se_rulesfile[$i]\n" );
                $k++;
            }

            #exit from child process

            exit 0;
        }
```

The following code is basically the parent waiting for the child to terminate and other checks which I am not displaying due to the length of the question.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why are you taking a data structure that looks reasonable and flattening it into multiple arrays?

Comment: I hope there's more to your YAML file than that, as it has a number of aliases that are undefined. Please show enough data for us to run your code and try this for ourselves

Comment: *"I don't get the desire results"* is a classy variation on *"it doesn't work"*, and isn't a proper problem description. It tells us nothing. There is no way we can help unless you show your *real, complete* data. By the way, "parsing" is what `YAML::XS` does. After that you're just messing with the Perl data structure, probably unnecessarily as [**Matt Jacob** says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833376/acessing-array-of-array-of-hash-pointers#comment65034523_38833376)

Comment: @Borodin : I have updated my yaml file , please have a look at it now and let me know if you need any other info. Also i know i am messing with the data structure but i am new to perl so this is how i did, gradually with experience i will improve but for now if u have a better approach do let me know. my problem seems to be with the same array is being filled for rulesfile

Comment: @hanish You updated your "YAML" file but you did not read flyx answer thoroughly enough. The answer clearly states in the first paragraph that you cannot have alias to anchors. The YAML 1.2 specs state "In the representation graph, a node may appear in more than one collection. When serializing such data, the *first* occurrence of the node is identified by an anchor". If your parser doesn't complain about that, you should use a different parser.  Apart from that `run_target_platform` is indented only one space, where the `stand_alone_execution` has two, making this incorrect YAML.

Comment: Does your parser really parse this, what you present here?

Comment: @Anthon yes it does parse properly, i have added the space... this is a legacy code which i can't change from the scratch as of now. this is just the added functionality which i have introduced and its causing errors ( not completely errors but it's not giving me desired results).

Comment: You still did not specify what you mean by *I don't get the desired results*. What results *are* you getting?

Answer (score 0):

In your YAML file, you use aliases to anchors which are not defined at all (`rulesid_03`, `rulesid_04`) or somewhere after the alias in the YAML stream (`rulesid_01`, others). Both leads to invalid YAML.

Moreover, you have indentation issues. `run_target_platforms` is less indented than the previous keys `rules_file` and `standalone_execution`. This is also invalid. Finally, this probably does not do what you want:

```
- run_target_id: &runid_01
  target_connection_info: 
  run_target_hostname: 
  run_target_username: 
  run_target_password:
```

It is a list item that contains a mapping. The first key of the mapping is `run_target_id` and its corresponding value is empty, but annotated with the anchor `runid_01`. You probably want to make the rest of the keys in this mapping to be part of a child mapping which is the value of the first key.

Here is a modified YAML with proper anchors, aliases and indentation:

```
rules_file: 
- rules_file_id: &rulesid_01 
    name: tpsm_rulesfile_LE 
    hostname:       

- rules_file_id: &rulesid_02
    name: tpsm_rulesfile_BE        
    hostname:  

run_target_platforms: 
- run_target_id: &runid_01
    target_connection_info: 
    run_target_hostname: 
    run_target_username: 
    run_target_password: 

- run_target_id: &runid_02
    target_connection_info: 
    run_target_hostname: 
    run_target_username: 
    run_target_password: 

standalone_execution:  
- utpsm_executable: &seid_01   
    name: tpsm_BE         
    rulesfile: [*rulesid_02,*rulesid_01]
    target_list: [*runid_01]

- utpsm_executable: &seid_02
    name: tpsm_LE         
    rulesfile: []
    target_list: [*runid_02]
```

Note that I removed `*rulesid_03,*rulesid_04` because they do not exist. You can of course add content with those anchors and then re-add the aliases.

Comment: Thanks. i had tried to keep it minimalist...i have corrected it pls check and let me know if u can help with resolving the data structures

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you. Looks like the Perl parser for YAML is a bit to forgiving.